# move selected elements up and down and save the changed order in an array so that the order is saved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

My listbox contains values(AllLinks) from javascript array of objects.

```
[{"AllLinks":"LinkOne","LinkURL":"http://www.Link1.com","Order":"0"},{"AllLinks":"Link3","LinkURL":"http://www.Link3.com","Order":"2"},{"AllLinks":"Link4","LinkURL":"http://www.Link4.com","Order":"3"},{"AllLinks":"Link5","LinkURL":"http://www.Link5.com","Order":"4"}]
```

I want to move the selected elements up and down and also want to save the changed order in array so that it can be saved back in sharepoint list.
The following code changes the order perfectly but how do i save and retain the values

```
function MoveUp(lst){
if(lst.selectedIndex == -1)
    alert('Please select an Item to move up.');
else
{
    if(lst.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        alert('First element cannot be moved up');
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        var tempValue = lst.options[lst.selectedIndex].value;
        var tempIndex = lst.selectedIndex-1;
        lst.options[lst.selectedIndex].value = lst.options[lst.selectedIndex-1].value;
        lst.options[lst.selectedIndex-1].value = tempValue;
        var tempText = lst.options[lst.selectedIndex].text;
        lst.options[lst.selectedIndex].text = lst.options[lst.selectedIndex-1].text;
        lst.options[lst.selectedIndex-1].text = tempText;
        lst.selectedIndex = tempIndex;

    }
}
return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creating global variables? Those values will be saved while you remain on the page. If you need to store them locally or in a session you can consider using localStorage or sessionStorage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>            
        <title>Ejemplo sessionStorage</title>   
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script>

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#boton-guardar').click(function(){        
     
        var nom = document.getElementById("nombretxt").value;
        var apel = document.getElementById("apellidotxt").value;
        
        sessionStorage.setItem("Nombre", nom);
        sessionStorage.setItem("Apellido", apel);
       
        document.getElementById("nombretxt").value = "";
        document.getElementById("apellidotxt").value = "";
    });   
});


$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#boton-cargar').click(function(){                       
        
        var nombre = sessionStorage.getItem("Nombre");
        var apellido = sessionStorage.getItem("Apellido");
           
        document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = nombre;
        document.getElementById("apellido").innerHTML = apellido; 
    });   
});

</script>
</head>
        
<center><h1>Ejemplo - sessionStorage</h1>
              
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombretxt"> <br>  <br>   
<input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellidotxt"><br>  <br>
<button id="boton-guardar">Guardar</button><br>
           
<hr />
Nombre almacenado:
<label type="text" id="nombre"></label><br>                          
Apellido almacenado:
<label "text" id="apellido"></label><br>

<button id="boton-cargar">
Cargar elementos
</button>
</center>

<hr />


</body> 
</html>
```